# Incorporating Accordion widget into Squarespace 6

Tags: jquery, css, squarespace

I have been trying to figure out how to incorporate accordion widgets into one of my Squarespace 6 page. Basically like how it is laid out here: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

However, with Squarespace, JQuery may not work... is there something that I can do with CSS instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do anything with jquery in squarespace.

Use `code injection Block` if you want to run functionality on whole website.(on all pages).

If you want to use jquery for particluar page.then you can use simply `Code blocks`. available on every page.
let me know.if anything is not clear.

check following links also.

http://help.squarespace.com/guides/can-i-add-custom-html-css-and-javascript

http://help.squarespace.com/guides/using-code-injection

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice tutorial I came across. It purely uses CSS to achieve the results. It is done in 3 parts:
1) Preparing your content and giving it an class for reference.
2) Writing the basic CSS for the accordion; a) Style the boxes, b) Style the headings c) Arrange the content child to display properly.
3) Using :Target Pseudo-Class Selector to create the UI effect.

You can find the full tutorial by clicking the link below.
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, links break and then the answer is useless.  Please edit your answer to include a quick summary of the contents of the link.

Comment: @pokecu22: Thanks for pointing that out. Though I have been around for a while, never on the contributing side.